# Codeigniter Routing methods

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller Pages, am using this controller to load the product details and division details.

When am loading a division the URL loaded in the browser in the below manner

**URL:** www.example.com/pages/division_details/$1

but i need the URL to be loaded in the browser is

**URL:** www.example.com/$1

the controller and method name(pages/division_details) must be replaced and the $1 value i,e. the value which is obtained from the database will be loaded

same as in the case of product details

**URL:** www.example.com/pages/product_details/$1

**URL:** www.example.com/$1

the controller and method name(pages/product_details) must be replaced and the $1 value i,e. the value which is obtained from the database will be loaded

How should I place routing method so that i should not see the controller and method name in the URL ?

Comment: check the official document https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html and update your post what you did accordingly.

Comment: updated the post @Deep3015

Comment: It is not possible same `route` for two action in `CI`. it can be define two route for your problem.

Comment: The only way of doing something like this is creating your own route handler where you check what's inside the $1 and then define where it belongs. However this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You may create it by using some text like

```
$route['division_(:num)'] = 'pages/division_details/$1';
$route['product_(:num)'] = 'pages/product_details/$1';
```

Now your URL will be something like

> www.example.com/division_$1

and for product

> www.example.com/product_$1